# PostgreSQL JDBC Driver logUnclosedConnections is not working

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I'm testing PostgreSQL JDBC Driver additional properties to check whether it can help to find out connection leaks. Even though I've deliberately not closed the Connection, PreparedStatement, ResultSet, no errors are reported.

How can I make `logUnclosedConnections` work.

Here is my sample program

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {

    Properties dbProps = new Properties();
    dbProps.setProperty( "user", "xxxxxxx" );
    dbProps.setProperty( "password", "xxxxxxxxxx" );
    dbProps.setProperty( "logServerErrorDetail", "true" );
    dbProps.setProperty( "logUnclosedConnections", "true" );
    dbProps.setProperty( "loggerLevel", "DEBUG" );

    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:postgresql://xxxxx.xxxxx.xxx:xxx/xxxxx", dbProps );

    try {
        PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement( "select count(*) from xx.xx limit 10" );

        ResultSet rSet = pstmt.executeQuery();

        while ( rSet.next() ) {
            System.out.println( "count is " + rSet.getInt( 1 ) );

        }

    } catch ( Exception e ) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The result is

```
count is 687
Sep 08, 2021 12:21:44 PM org.postgresql.Driver connect
FINE: Connecting with URL: jdbc:postgresql://xxxxx.xxxx.xxxx:xxx/xxxx
Sep 08, 2021 12:21:44 PM org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection <init>
FINE: PostgreSQL JDBC Driver 42.2.23
Sep 08, 2021 12:21:44 PM org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection setDefaultFetchSize
FINE:   setDefaultFetchSize = 0
Sep 08, 2021 12:21:44 PM org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection setPrepareThreshold
FINE:   setPrepareThreshold = 5
Sep 08, 2021 12:21:44 PM org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl openConnectionImpl
FINE: Trying to establish a protocol version 3 connection to xxxx.xxxx.xxx:xxx
Sep 08, 2021 12:21:44 PM org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl tryConnect
FINE: Receive Buffer Size is 65,536
Sep 08, 2021 12:21:44 PM org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl tryConnect
FINE: Send Buffer Size is 65,536
Sep 08, 2021 12:21:44 PM org.postgresql.ssl.MakeSSL convert
FINE: converting regular socket connection to ssl
```

### Edit 1

Changes as suggested by **@Scary Wombat** and **@Stephen C**, but the result is same.

**No report on unclosed connection**.

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {

    Properties dbProps = new Properties();
    dbProps.setProperty( "user", "postgres" );
    dbProps.setProperty( "password", "AuR0ra$dba#$" );
    dbProps.setProperty( "logServerErrorDetail", "true" );
    dbProps.setProperty( "logUnclosedConnections", "true" );
    dbProps.setProperty( "loggerLevel", "DEBUG" );

    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:postgresql://devdbmaster.koncert.com:5499/dev_koncert_v10.5", dbProps );

    try {

        for ( int i = 0; i < 100; i++ ) {
            PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement( "select count(*) from cl.users limit 10" );

            ResultSet rSet = pstmt.executeQuery();

            while ( rSet.next() ) {
                System.out.println( "count is " + rSet.getInt( 1 ) );

            }

            Thread.sleep( 10 );
        }

    } catch ( Exception e ) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    conn = null;
    System.gc();
    Thread.sleep( 1 );
}
```

### Edit 2

added `conn = null;` before `System.gc();` as suggested by **@Gus** and **@Stephen C**

Comment: *Eventually these objects will be garbage collected and the finalize() method will be called which will close the Connection if caller has neglected to do this himself.*  I guess that in this simplistic code no GC is occurring.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Any thoughts on how to make this work

Comment: Loop around a few hundred times, with maybe some sleep time.

Comment: I think what's happening here is that the whole VM is being torn down before the individual finalizers need to run.  Notice that you call `System.gc()` while the connection is still in scope, and assigned to the variable `conn`.  So, it can't be collected -- it's still in use as far the JVM is concerned, and certainly not inaccessible.  Possibly just setting `conn` to null before calling for the gc would be sufficient.

Comment: @Gus Tried as suggested still the result is same

Answer (score 2):

According to the PostgreSQL JDBC driver documentation:

> `logUnclosedConnections = boolean`
>
> Clients may leak `Connection` objects by failing to call its `close()` method. Eventually these objects will be garbage collected and the `finalize()` method will be called which will close the `Connection` if caller has neglected to do this himself. The usage of a finalizer is just a stopgap solution.
>
> To help developers detect and correct the source of these leaks the `logUnclosedConnections` URL parameter has been added. It captures a stacktrace at each `Connection` opening and if the `finalize()` method is reached without having been closed the stacktrace is printed to the log.

So, what you are testing here is a mechanism that is intended for debugging faulty code that is leaking `Connection` objects.

The problem is that you are not testing it the right way.  As the description states, the mechanism *depends* on the garbage collector finding unreachable `Connection` objects.  For this to work, 3 things need to happen:

1. The GC needs to run.
2. The GC needs to find the unreachable `Connection`.  Note that the GC does not guarantee to find all unreachable objects each time it runs.
3. After the GC runs, the unreachable `Connection` objects that it has found need to be finalized.

It your test, you create and use a `Connection` and then `main` ends, terminating the JVM.  By the time `main` ends the GC has not run.  So the leaked `Connection` is not detected.

To make this test "work" you need to add the following at the end of the loop body;

```
  rRet = null;
  pstmt = null;
```

Then add at the end of the `main` method:

```
  conn = null;
  System.gc();
  Thread.sleep(1);
```

The null assignments makes the `Connection` unreachable.  (Note that the `PreparedStatement` and `ResultSet` will both refer to the `Connection`.  We need to destroy all of the references that could make the `Connection` reachable.)

The `System.gc()` statement *asks* the JVM to run the GC.

The `Thread.sleep(1)` statement waits for a further second ... so that the JVM gets a chance to run the connection finalizer before the JVM ends.

---

I say "work" in quotes for a couple of reasons:

1. You shouldn't do this kind of thing in production code.  Calling `System.gc()` is inefficient.  A better idea is to just let the GC run when the JVM thinks it is necessary.
2. In fact, `System.gc()` is not guaranteed to do anything at all.  Likewise, you cannot rely on finalizers running immediately.  So there are scenarios where the two added statements won't work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Stephen C. As you suggested, tried doing the changes but the result is same. There is no report on unclosed connections.

Comment: Ah ... yes.  Set `conn` to `null` before calling `System.gc()`.  The `conn` variable is likely to still be reachable ... until `main` exits.

Comment: `conn = null;
System.gc();` 
 still same

Comment: Assign `null` to `pstmt` and `rSet` as well.  They will have references to the connection object.

Comment: Note that I am not testing this 'cos I don't want to install PostgreSQL on my machine ...

Comment: No problem on that.  `pstmt = null; rSet = null;` It's still same

Comment: Then I am out of ideas.